# Rust-analyzer doesn't work with FetchWorkspaceError (os error 5)

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-cargo, rust-analyzer

I just start to learn rust.
I already install rust and cargo on my laptop

```
PS C:\Users\USER> rustc --version
rustc 1.73.0 (cc66ad468 2023-10-03)
PS C:\Users\USER> rustup --version
rustup 1.26.0 (5af9b9484 2023-04-05)
info: This is the version for the rustup toolchain manager, not the rustc compiler.
info: The currently active `rustc` version is `rustc 1.73.0 (cc66ad468 2023-10-03)`
PS C:\Users\USER> cargo --version
cargo 1.73.0 (9c4383fb5 2023-08-26)
```

I want to code rust on vscode, but my rust-analyzer doesn't work.
It reports this error

```
[ERROR rust_analyzer::main_loop] FetchWorkspaceError:
rust-analyzer failed to load workspace: Failed to load the project at C:\Users\USER\muic\iccs311\lecture\Cargo.toml: Failed to query rust toolchain version at C:\Users\USER\muic\iccs311\lecture, is your toolchain setup correctly?: "C:\\Users\\USER\\.cargo\\bin" "--version" failed: Access is denied. (os error 5)
```

I don't know why access is denied

I also open the entire directory, inside my directory already contain Cargo.toml

[files structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9mAX.png)

[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzlOG.png)

Comment: It looks like `C:\Users\USER\muic\iccs311\lecture` is your project path. Does the file `Cargo.toml` exist in this path? In vscode do you open the entire directory, or only open some files independently? Opening files independently seems to lead to the error. It's not clear so please provide more details.

Comment: @rustyhu yes, I open the entire directory, and the directory also contain Cargo.toml, but it still doesn't work. The error says "is your toolchain setup correctly?" how can I check this